# Powershell implementation to pipe array into command

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following Powershell command to copy one user's Mercurial.ini file into another user's profile:

```
> copy $env:USERPROFILE\..\benm\Mercurial.ini $env:USERPROFILE\..\alex\Mercurial.ini
```

That works well. However, I'd like to write it in such as way so that I can do something like the following, specifying the users up front and piping them in to the copy command:

```
> "benm","alex" | copy "$env:UserProfile\..\$_[0]\Mercurial.ini" "$env:UserProfile\..\$_[1]\Mercurial.ini"
```

However, the above doesn't work. Is there an elegant way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
,("benm","alex") | 
foreach {copy "$env:UserProfile\..\$($_[0])\Mercurial.ini" "$env:UserProfile\..\$($_[1])\Mercurial.ini"}
```

The ,("benm","alex")  syntax makes the input from the pipeline a 2D array

```
 PS C:\> $x = ,("benm","alex")
 PS C:\> $x[0]
 benm
 alex
 PS C:\> $x[0][0]
 benm
 PS C:\> $x[0][1]
 alex
```

The Powershell pipeline will automatically "unroll" arrays and collections into a stream of objects, but only one level deep for nested arrays. By making it a 2D array, it "unrolls" the first level, and passes the nested  array through the pipelile intact.

Comment: Good catch.That's a consequence of using an array element in a string argument.  You must use a sub-expression to get the array element to expand.

Comment: You might want to explain what `,( )` is doing. It's a neat trick.

Comment: Updated the answer with some explanation of the ,( ) syntax.

Comment: is there a way to get powershell to *not* unroll the array? I like your trick, but it seems a bit much

Comment: Not that I know of.  It's pretty well hard-wired into it.  That's how you get an array into the pipeline. You can give it the user names in an argumentlist, but that's not using the pipeline and you'd have to use $args instead of $_.